# Using C++ from Python? (not boost)

Tags: c++, python

I'm currently using boost-python to wrap a small C++ library and make it usable from Python.  However, I'd like to stop using boost (mainly due to reasons relating to building/linking).  So what other options are there?

Is there something that's equally convenient to use?

Comment: You'd probably be better off opening a new question about your building/linking problems. boost::python is pretty nice.

Comment: No, because my building/linking problem is well know: it's bloody difficult to find out what arguments to pass to the compiler/linker, because boost doesn't have something like pkg-config.

Answer (score 2):

There's Riverbank's [SIP](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/intro), Beazley's [Swig](http://www.swig.org/), and Scott's/Dubois'/Furnish's [Cxx](http://cxx.sourceforge.net/).  See also [this page](http://language-binding.net/#pygccxml-package) with other potentially relevant projects (but no direct answer to your immediate needs, I believe).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

Answer (score 0):

[Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html)'s syntax is very Pythonic, breaking the rules only where necessary.

Comment: Yep, but it doesn't do C++ -- in my answers, I listed only projects that do (SIP and Cxx are C++ only, SWIG supports multiple languages).

Comment: @Alex: Then how come the page at the link I gave exists?

Comment: There are people saying that Cython does C++ well in 0.13, but the latest release is 0.12.1 :(

The main question however is whether I can easily use a library, written in Cython, from Python (CPython).